# JavaFX CSS Styling: Change Highlight color of Selected Tabs

Tags: css, javafx

I'm trying to change the highlighted color of selected tabs. It seems the standard is blue and it is not the `-fx-border-color` as it adds a border on top of blue highlight. I was wondering what property changes this color. See images below:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
.tab-pane:focused > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab:selected .focus-indicator {-fx-border-color: red}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a combination of `-fx-focus-color` (which defaults to `#039ED3`) and `-fx-faint-focus-color` (which is just a semi-transparent version: `#039ED322`).