# JavaFx Tab - Appearance differs from SceneBuilder

Tags: css, user-interface, javafx, tabs

**Context**: Using SceneBuilder to build a Tabbed Pane application

**Issue**: I notice the visualization as seen in Scene Builder - Preview option & that when viewed after executing the program look different.

**Note**:

1. I am using the standard Tab & TabPane option available in Scene builder.
2. I use Scenebuilder 10.0.0 (executable Jar) & Java JDK 10
3. I have not applied any CSS styling, but even those suggested in the 2 links below did not help

**Expectation**: The output after program execution is the same as that observed in SceneBuilder-preview option.

I referred to [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34211310/remove-the-glowing-border-from-focused-tab-with-css) & [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36779642/javafx-css-styling-change-highlight-color-of-selected-tabs) but dint help.

**Scene Builder Output**:

[image]

**Program Execution Output** :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application looks different from SceneBuilder preview because you're not using the same user-agent stylesheet theme.

JavaFx application uses its Modena theme by default, while you set SceneBuilder to use Gluon Mobile Light theme for design/preview (main menu: Preview -> Theme).

JavaFx doesn't come with Gluon Mobile Light theme, and if you want to use it, you need to setup your project to use Gluon Mobile SDK/library ([Gluon Mobile](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/5.0.1/#_getting_started)).

The other option is to write custom css:

```
//custom-theme.css

.tab-pane > .tab-header-area {
  -fx-padding: 0;
}

.tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .tab-header-background {
  -fx-background-color: #E1E1E1, white;
  -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1px 0;
}

.tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab {
  -fx-background-color: white;
  -fx-background-insets: 0 0 1px 0;     
  -fx-padding: 1.5em 1em;
}

.tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab >.tab-container >.tab-label {
  -fx-text-fill: #63B5F6;
}

.tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab:selected {
  -fx-background-color: #2092ED, white;
  -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 2px 0;
}

.tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab:selected >.tab-container >.tab-label {
  -fx-text-fill: #2095F3;
}

.tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab:selected >.tab-container >.focus-indicator {
  -fx-opacity: 0;
}
```

add the file to your project (put it in "src/main/resources" or somewhere else in classpath) and apply it to your application:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add("custom-theme.css");
```

[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6D8r.png)

Comment: Appreciate the inputs. Had missed out that check.